# How long does it take to create a view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

The origin table, it look line this.

```
TIME                 | NAME       | VALUE
---------------------+------------+--------
2020-11-26 11:12:13  |  Alice     | 10.51
2020-11-26 11:13:13  |  Bob       | 12.54
2020-11-26 11:14:13  |  Cary      | 13.53
2020-11-26 11:17:13  |  David     | 14.54
2020-11-26 12:12:13  |  Alice     | 11.4
2020-11-26 12:13:13  |  Bob       | 12.5
2020-11-26 12:14:13  |  Cary      | 30.12
2020-11-26 12:17:13  |  David     | 4.04
.....
```

But there are many number of data, may be more than 100,000,000. And it save data now.

And I want get average value by day. like this.

```
DAY            | Alice  | Bob   | Cary   | David
---------------+--------+-------+--------+------
2020-11-26     | 10.955 | 12.52 | 21.825 | 9.29
2020-11-27     | ....
```

I have SQL for get average value by day but it spend too much time.

```
SELECT          
    date_format(TIME, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'DATE',
    AVG(CASE WHEN  'Alice' THEN VALUE END) AS 'Alice',
    AVG(CASE WHEN  'Bob' THEN VALUE END) AS 'Bob', 
    AVG(CASE WHEN  'Cary' THEN VALUE END) AS 'Cary', 
    AVG(CASE WHEN  'David' THEN VALUE END) AS 'David'
FROM data_log
GROUP BY DAY(TIME);
```

it spend 20sec, when I want get one day. and spend 20min, when I get two days.

So I create view for get average value by day and select the view.

And my question is

Does the view update itself every time data is stored in the original table?

Is it spend many time to select the view?

The original table already has over 100 million data. Is it spend many time to create a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view simply stores the code for the query.  When you access the view, everything needs to be recalculated.

Hence, a normal view is not going to be faster than the query itself.

Some databases support *materialized views*.  These are different from regular views because the stored the data, precalculated.  MySQL does not support materialized views, however.

If you want only one day's data, run the original query with a `WHERE` clause limiting data to that one day.